# I have data for two financial years, I want to show cumulative data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `mpr` in which financial data for two years is stored. I want to see the cumulative data for the current month and this financial year.

My query is

```
select SUM(financialtarget) 
from MPR 
where mpryear <= '2014-15' and month <= 6
```

It's showing all the month data where month is below than 6, while I need only sum of the all months in financialyear = 2013-14 and financialyear is 2014-15 and month is below and equal to 6.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The `where` condition you need is a little bit more complicated:

```
where mpryear < '2014-15' or 
      (mpryear = '2014-15' and month <= 6)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer in my case financial year start from Apr to March so it will show only apr to june data it showing jan feb and march data also.